# Command 'rvm' not found, but there are 19 similar ones

Tags: ruby, windows, rvm, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Hi I have installed `rvm` in `wsl`. After installation I added it in the `.bashrc` file:
`source "/etc/profile.d/rvm.sh"`
also `$PATH` gives this output:

```
-bash: /home/suvodip/.nvm/versions/node/v12.18.3/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/mnt/c/pik/:/mnt/c/Windows/system32:/mnt/c/Windows:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/Wbem:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/OpenSSH/:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/NVIDIA Corporation/PhysX/Common:/mnt/c/Program Files/NVIDIA Corporation/NVIDIA NvDLISR:/mnt/c/Users/smond/AppData/Roaming/nvm:/mnt/c/Program Files/nodejs:/mnt/c/Program Files/Git/cmd:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Yarn/bin/:/mnt/c/Users/smond/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38-32/Scripts/:/mnt/c/Users/smond/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38-32/:/mnt/c/Users/smond/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps:/mnt/c/Users/smond/AppData/Roaming/nvm:/mnt/c/Program Files/nodejs:/mnt/c/Users/smond/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/bin:/mnt/c/Users/smond/AppData/Local/Yarn/bin:/snap/bin:/usr/local/rvm/src/rvm/bin:
```

But `rvm install ruby` command is not working, please help me figure out this

Answer (score 2):

This is how I solved it:

Go to root directory and run this two commands:

```
gpg2 --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3 7D2BAF1CF37B13E2069D6956105BD0E739499BDB
\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
```

Follow this link: http://rvm.io/ then install any version of rvm you want.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you followed the instructions to install as found here [ubuntu_rvm](https://github.com/rvm/ubuntu_rvm)

And when you say added it into `.bashrc` you mean you ran `echo 'source "/etc/profile.d/rvm.sh"' >> ~/.bashrc`. Your path should contain something like `/home/suvodip/.rvm` but i dont see it, are you sure you followed all the install instructions?

Then opening a new terminal should do the trick.

Maybe try running `which -a rvm` or `whereis rvm` to see if anything is found. Or failing that `sudo find / -name rvm 2>/dev/null` to see if the install worked and where the files went. Please update your question with all the details here. thanks

Answer (score -1):

I solved it like this:

run the command

```bash
$ whereis rvm
```

In my case it was: rvm: `/usr/share/rvm /usr/share/rvm/bin/rvm`

Then open the shell startup file with the command:

```
$ nano ~/.bashrc
```

At the end of the file paste: `export PATH="/usr/share/rvm/bin:$PATH`

With your proper rvm address!